# Dynamics- Projectiles and the envelope equation

Tags: projectile-motion

The question asks:
A ball is launched from the origin O at ground level V
We've been asked to derive the envelope of trajectories equation which I did fine. 
Then it says:
A vertical wall of height H is placed a horizontal distance D from O. Find the minimum height H=Hmin that will ensure the ball cannot get over the wall. 
How would I go about doing this? 
Im guessing as we've been asked to derive the envelope equation we use this? Not sure where to go from here!

Comment: It the top of the wall lies above the envelope, then the ball cannot get over it.

Comment: Thanks @almagest See i thought that so then z<H but where do I go from there? If I insert these variables into the envelope equation I get a quadratic for the velocity not the height H?

Comment: What is your envelope equation?

Comment: @almagest z= v^2/2g - gx^2/2v^2

Comment: Ok. Remember that $v$ is fixed - it is the launch velocity. So what you have is an equation that gives the maximum height $z$ as a function of $x$. So plug in $x=D$ (the distance to the wall) and the resulting value of $z$ gives you the minimum height $H$ for the wall.

Comment: so my equation is
V^2/2g - gD^2/2V^2 < H ?

Comment: Yes, although you are asked for $H_{min}$

Comment: How does that change it? Sorry I've been staring at this for hours I cannot seem to figure it out!

Comment: It is correct that any $H$ greater than $v^2/2g-gD^2/2v^2$ will block the ball. If the question asked for the *minimum* $H$ that will block the ball, then the answer is $v^2/2g-gD^2/2v^2$.

Comment: I have that... but it then asks me to consider the trajectory with which the ball hits the top of the wall when H=Hmin and find the speed and it gave me 0!

Comment: The speed at which it hits the top of the wall? You can get that by conservation of energy.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that :(. Ok thanks for helping!

Comment: Gravitational potential energy + kinetic energy is conserved. So $\frac{1}{2}v^2=gh+\frac{1}{2}u^2$, where $u$ is the speed when it is at height $h$ (and $v$ is the initial speed).

Comment: We've never really done that with this kind of problem before, only ever using the trajectory equation or envelope equation Is there another way to compute it? If not I'll do it that way! Thanks